# Tornado StaticFileHandler path for multiple regex capture group

Tags: tornado

From an URL of the form: `/foo/(.*)/bar/(.*)` , I want to serve files, where the actual path is computed from the 2 captured groups. My problem is that StaticFileHandler's get() takes only 1 path parameter. Is there a way to get this to work, without having to reimplement most of StaticFileHandler's methods ?

My current workaround is to capture everything: `(/foo/.*/bar/.*)` , but then I have to reparse a similar regex inside an overriden get_absolute_path().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that without extending `StaticFileHandler`. It would be a tiny change:

```
from tornado import gen, web

class CustomStaticFileHandler(web.StaticFileHandler):

    def get(self, part1, part2, include_body=True):
        # mangle path
        path = "dome_{}_combined_path_{}".format(part1, part2)
        # back to staticfilehandler
        return super().get(path, include_body)

    # if you need to use coroutines on mangle use 
    #
    # @gen.coroutine
    # def get(self, part1, part2, include_body=True):
    #     path = yield some_db.get_path(part1, part2)
    #     yield super().get(path, include_body)

app = web.Application([
    (r"/foo/(.*)/bar/(.*)", CustomStaticFileHandler, {"path": "/tmp"}),
])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. It should be noted that you also need to override validate_absolute_path OR make sure what "path" you gave at handler declaration is a parent directory of every path you will generate.